# Create a file in /public using dist file

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm using Play 2.5 and I have written a code, in Java, to create a file in /app/public folder, I parametrized the path in application.conf. After that I created a dist file and when I tried to call that method from my dist file, the file is not getting generated in /public folder. Is it not able to detect the path?

`file.create{
  path = "public/"
}`

Edit: Java Code -

```
String filePath = conf.getString("file.create.path") + "Excel_file.xlsx";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

Comment: Can you post the Java code and show how you tried to call it?

Comment: @RichDougherty I added java code, fileoutputstream created the file at that location, but when I call that method to trigger this functionality in dist mode, it doesn't create the file in public/.

Comment: Did you try to create the file? You are trying to open the file - try to write something and close the stream. Look at the logs and see what is the exception it is throwing.

Comment: You may want to print out the `filePath` to see where you're putting it. Since the path doesn't start with `/` it will be relative to the current directory. You might want to use the Java file APIs to convert the file path to an absolute path so you can be sure where it's going.

Comment: @RichDougherty Thanks, giving an absolute file path worked for me. I'm really sorry for replying this late.